# Configure pocketsphinx keyword search without a file

Tags: speech-recognition, pocketsphinx-android

I know that the method addKeywordSearch is available. However, it requires the creation of a file. In my case, that creates some overhead in my app which I am trying to avoid.
I have been trying to find documentation on the website, but its very limited. Is there any specific format I should use to tell the addKeyphraseSearch method the limit of each word?

To make things clear, using the addKeywordSearch method, I have to create a file that looks like this:
next
previous
go to step

Is there any way to have those 3 commands but using the addKeyphraseSearch method?
For example, I was thinking that something like addKeyphraseSearch(SEARCH,"next\nprevious\ngo to step") would do the trick, but it doesnt

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is a way, add corresponding function in pocketsphinx, update swig bindings. 
You are welcome to submit a patch with the changes.

Overall, keyword thresholds must be different for each keyword, so it's recommended to tune thresholds first and use file to initialize search with several keywords. If you want to give user an option to specify his own keywords, it will work less efficiently because user will not be able to properly configure threshold.